# 4x4 grid with no three cells of one colour in a line

Tags: mathematics

Can you paint the cells of a 4x4 grid in two colours such that no three cells of the same colour lie on a straight line passing through their center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

> X X O O
>  O O X X
>  X X O O
>  O O X X

Comment: Yes you got it!